# flatten HTML to text object-c with mailcore2

Tags: html, mailcore2

I am using mailcore2 and I have below Scenario.

I want to display html and summary but only want to download the content 1 time, so I decide to load the HTML content and flatten (remove html tags) html to text:

1. Get the HTML content using `htmlBodyRenderingOperationWithMessage`
2. I don't want to use `plainTextBodyRenderingOperationWithMessage` to load the textbody, I want to flatten HTML from the `htmlBodyRenderingOperationWithMessage`.

Do we have any export function from mailcore2 to flatten HTML to text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a method available in MailCore 2 to "flatten" HTML. You can use:

```
-[NSString mco_flattenHTML]
```

It will remove all the html tags and non-visible text from the string.